# scale parameter is producing a displacement in scipy distribution

Tags: python, scipy

I am doing some stuff with the [SciPy's `levy_stable`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.levy_stable.html) distribution. The documentation says:

> `levy_stable.pdf(x, alpha, beta, loc, scale)` is identically equivalent to `levy_stable.pdf(y, alpha, beta) / scale` with `y = (x - loc) / scale`.

Then, I understand that `levy_stable.pdf(x, alpha=1, beta=1, loc=0, scale=10)` should be a stretched-around-0 but not displaced version of `levy_stable.pdf(x, alpha=1, beta=1, loc=0, scale=1)`. However, I am getting this:

[image]

Note how the maximum is at a negative value when `scale=1` but at a positive value when `scale>=5`, which means that it has been displaced. Why? Bug or am I missing something? In other easier distributions, such as `norm`, the `loc` and `scale` parameters do exactly what you expect given their names: Translate and stretch the distribution. Actually, for [the `moyal` distribution](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.moyal.html), which is supposed to be an approximation to the other distribution, it behaves as expected:

[image]

The code to produce those plots is this one:

```py
from scipy.stats import levy_stable, moyal
import numpy
import plotly.express as px
import pandas

data = []
for loc in [0]:
    for scale in [1,5,10]:
        distributions = {
            'levy_stable': levy_stable(alpha=1,beta=1,loc=loc,scale=scale), 
            'moyal': moyal(loc=loc,scale=scale),
        }
        for name,dist in distributions.items():
            x = numpy.linspace(loc-5*scale,loc+30*scale,999)
            df = pandas.DataFrame(
                {
                    'x': x,
                    'x/scale': x/scale,
                    'y': dist.pdf(x),
                }
            )
            df['loc'] = loc
            df['scale'] = scale
            df['distribution'] = name
            data.append(df)
data = pandas.concat(data)

fig = px.line(
    data,
    x = 'x/scale',
    y = 'y',
    facet_row = 'scale',
    color = 'distribution',
)
fig.update_yaxes(matches=None)
fig.write_html(f'deleteme/levy_stable_bug.html')
```

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a bug.  I submitted a bug report here: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/19140

The PDF calculation for the Levy stable distribution is complicated. There is no closed-form solution, and SciPy implements a couple different methods to compute it.  The SciPy implementation in `levy_stable` has an extra attribute called `parameterization` that can be set to control the internal parameterization.  The default is `levy_stable.parameterization = 'S1'`, and this version has the bug.  As a work-around, add the line

```
levy_stable.parameterization = 'S0'
```

to your code to select the alternative parameterization.  The `S0` parameterization does not appear to have the bug.

(So far, I have only tested this with SciPy 1.11.2.)

Comment: It does not seem to change using the `'S0'` parameterization for me, it does exactly the same.

Comment: Strange, it works for me (but I haven't run *your* script).  My initial attempt didn't work, but that was because I misspelled `parameterization`.  If you are using an IDE or interactive shell, try completely exiting the program and running your code with a plain `python` command.  Which version of SciPy are you using?  If you don't know, you can check with `import scipy; print(scipy.__version__)`

Answer (score 0):

The `levy_stable` values are correct, but the documentation is missing the crucial fact that the equivalence claimed does not apply for the `S1` parameterization if `alpha == 1`.

In the `S1` parameterization if `alpha == 1`, `levy_stable.pdf(x, alpha, beta, loc, scale)` is equivalent to `levy_stable.pdf(y, alpha, beta) / scale` with `y = (x - loc - 2 * beta * scale * np.log(scale) / np.pi) / scale`.  See [Stable Distributions: Models for Heavy Tailed Data](https://edspace.american.edu/jpnolan/wp-content/uploads/sites/1720/2020/09/Chap1.pdf), pp. 8-9.

[image: Chart with three PDFs]

### Code demo

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import levy_stable


alpha = 1
beta = 1
loc = 1
scale = 3


x = np.linspace(-5, 10, 1000)
y1 = levy_stable.pdf(x, alpha, beta, loc=loc, scale=scale)
y2 = levy_stable.pdf((x-loc)/scale, alpha, beta)/scale

plt.plot(x, y1, '--', linewidth=1,
         label='pdf(x, alpha, beta, loc=loc, scale=scale)')
plt.plot(x, y2, alpha=0.4, linewidth=3,
         label='pdf((x-loc)/scale, alpha, beta)/scale')

# Calculate scaled y.
y = (x - loc - 2 * beta * scale * np.log(scale) / np.pi) / scale
y3 = levy_stable.pdf(y, alpha, beta)/scale
plt.plot(x, y3, alpha=0.4, linewidth=3,
         label='pdf(y, alpha, beta)/scale')

plt.legend(shadow=True, framealpha=1)
plt.grid(alpha=0.25)
plt.savefig('levy_stable_plot_resolved.png')
```